# Set default segment.bytes for kafka inside docker

Tags: apache-kafka

I use `confluentinc/cp-kafka` docker image. I am looking for a way how to set `segment.bytes` for all topics by default and also `retension.ms` for about `1 day`. I tried to pass env variables

[image]

But it doesn't seem to use it. I also tried `wurstmeister/kafka`, but there were the same problems.

I think it's a bit strange that there is no configurations for disk space usage. How to perform it?

Answer (score 1):

I used the following in my docker compose and it works:

```
      KAFKA_LOG_SEGMENT_BYTES: 5000000
```

Broker startup log:

```
broker             |    log.roll.ms = null
broker             |    log.segment.bytes = 5000000
broker             |    log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
```

Im using confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest docker image

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer, which image do you use? is it global setting for every topic?

Comment: Im using **confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest** and the setting makes the config the cluster default. once you add the variable in your docker compose you can check the startup logs to see if the config was changed